# The new riddle of the sphinx

Tags: riddle

I have come to Greece as a tourist. But when I was wondering alone I have come in contact with the sphinx. This time it has asked me a new riddle. The riddle is as follows

> What is it or who is it that walked on four legs, then on three, then on two and then again on four.

I asked the sphinx for mercy, so it gave me permission to ask the question on Puzzling Stack Exchange. I asked the sphinx if he could give me a hint, so the witty sphinx gave me a hint to a condition:
 that if anyone down-votes my question, he would not spare me. Please people, I'm relying on you to help me go back home. The hint is:

> Your answer lies within a movie.

Comment: My itching hand wants to reach for the down vote button...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not seen the movie, but I think the answer is:

> Benjamin Button (from the movie [The Curious Case of Benjamin Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Case_of_Benjamin_Button_%28film%29)).

Explanation:

> Based on the plot summary and the trailer, the Benjamin Button character ages in reverse.  So he first walks on crutches (four legs) as an old man, then uses a cane (three legs), then walks on two legs as an adult, and by the end of the movie is a baby (so I presume he is crawling on all fours).